# Java keystore certificate is not getting picked up when using HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, spring-boot, keystore

I'm trying to send a request with `HttpsURLConnection` to an endpoint with a custom SSL certificate but I am still getting `PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`.

```
  HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  connection.setSSLSocketFactory(
            utilService
                .getCertificate(
                    item.getCertificatePath(), item.getCertificatePassword())
                .getSocketFactory());
```

I have the certificates as files in the project, and I add them manually to the connection. The problem is that this works with some of the other websites I need, but there's one that still is throwing a 403 error.

I tried adding the certificate to the Java Keystore but the error still persists:

```
COPY /src/main/resources/transport.crt /home/transport.crt
RUN $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -file /home/transport.crt -alias certificate1 -keystore "/opt/openjdk-17/lib/security/cacerts" -trustcacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

I don't really understand why adding the certificate manually to the connection doesn't work, nor why doesn't it work when I add it to the key store.

Comment: Is the cert valid/matching - CN, SAN matches hostname, date range?

Comment: I just fixed it by downloading the certificate from their website and importing it into the Java keystore. Not sure why do I need to do that, should my transport certificate already cover that i.e. if I send a POST request without it it'll fail.

Comment: There must have been a problem with the 'transport certificate' - CN, SAN???